# Blender 2.91.2 Mantaflow fire + smoke simulation doesnt fully render in Eeevee (very little smoke and no fire at all) vs in solid object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I tried cleaning cache and changing its location to somewhere else, tried modular and all baking, still same result.
I tried changing to cycles but same result.
If needed, I am using AMD R9 380 4GB.
View in solid object.
[image]

Rendered image.
[image]

My domain settings.
[image]

My domain material shading.
[image]

SOLVED USING 2.93 ALPHA (RESULT):
[image]

Comment: You cannot use a _Principled BSDF_ shader for the volume, it's a surface shader. You should use the _Principled Volume_ shader. That's the quick explanation. Creating fire is a wide field, but to manage the first steps I would really suggest you watch any tutorial on how to create fire with Mantaflow, at least one because it looks like you need to first learn the basics. Not meaning to be rude, but fire is such a complex thing.

Comment: Yes, I removed the surface node now and only connected it to volume, the screenshot is the wrong one, sorry.

Comment: Could you please replace the incorrect screenshot with one of how it is currently configured?  It does look like you have not configured the volume shader properly.

Comment: Updated! This should be correct. Both flow and domain used the same shading.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Seems like it's the problem with 2.91.2 itself. Tested using 2.93 Alpha and it works well. Had to change blackbody intensity in shading editor of the domain and everything works well so far. Updated pictures in post.